# Supervision/mentorship norms and options for assistant professor

Tags: career-path, tenure-track, early-career, assistant-professor, mentoring

Currently I am an assistant professor in a research group of a field which is not my main field. I do have a group leader of course, but I only see him for my yearly performance evaluations. I do have my own collaborators outside of my university, but within my university I am relatively isolated. I do not really like this, but I also do not know if this is normal. So my question is

- is it normal to have any sort of regular meetings with your group leader as assistant professor, for example about your research line, or more high level coaching?
- if not, how do you learn the skills you need to be successful in academia?

Comment: When you say you are in a group- do you mean a department? Or are you in some sort of medical context? Something else?

Comment: Yes, you you could say a department. In this case the department has been split into smaller research groups, but I think that that does not matter so much for the question.

Comment: What country is this?

Answer (score 1):

Many universities I have been a part of have had a mentor/mentee program for new faculty. Often this was rather informal but encouraged by chairs. Usually the mentor was supposed to be someone other than one’s chair, although periodic meetings with the chair (maybe 3 a year) were also encouraged.

In terms of how to get mentorship more broadly, I would encourage you to look at the areas where you need mentorship or support more broadly and then identify specific people who could fill each role. Maybe the chair helps you with university politics things. Maybe your informal mentor helps you prioritize your projects.

In addition, I will encourage you to consider you could have peer support for some of your “mentorship” goals. I have a group chat online with 5 peers and we will have a daily check in and also talk about things like model specifications, the most important robustness checks, and how to respond to specific reviewer complaints.

For more information, the NCFDD group puts out a module on mentorship. You could also look at the concept of a “personal Board of Directors”.